# Python is slower than PHP to get Index Position

Tags: php, python, performance, python-2.7

I am surprise to find Python is slower than PHP to get Index Position. Is there a way to improve performance on Python?

For Example:

In PHP it took: 18.169965982437

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$needle = file_get_contents("needle.wav", false, null, 46);

foreach(range(0, 10000) as $num) {
   $haystack = file_get_contents("haystack.wav");
   $match = strpos($haystack,$needle);
}

$time_end = microtime(true);

$finishTime = $time_end - $time_start;
echo $finishTime;
?>
```

In Python it took: 23.6319999695

```
import time
import math
def microtime(get_as_float = False) :
    if get_as_float:
        return time.time()
    else:
        return '%f %d' % math.modf(time.time())

time_start = microtime(True)
needle = open("needle.wav","rb").read()

for x in range(0, 10000):
    haystack = open("haystack.wav","rb").read()
    match = haystack.index(needle[46:])

time_end = microtime(True)
finishTime = time_end - time_start
print finishTime
```

Comment: For one thing, you're cloning the entire needle after byte 46 in each iteration in python, but not in php.

Comment: What version of python do you run? 2? In that case you could use xrange which is faster.

Comment: Yes I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Why are you opening and reading the same file 10000 times? That's a real bottleneck.

Comment: @rubik He's doing it in both programs though. So while it does make the benchmark less realistic, it doesn't invalidate it.

Comment: @delnan: But we (= I) don't know how file are handled in PHP, it may be different.

Comment: @rubik It isn't, see http://php.net/file_get_contents ;-)

Comment: @rubik Because I will be doing a lot of Index Position in a real project. That is why I am doing this benchmark for testing.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: Yeah but one thing is to call index 10000 times, another is opening the file that many times.

Comment: @rubik Yeah but if you move opening the file outside of the loop. It is still slow than PHP.  For example: `needle = open("needle.wav","rb").read()[46:]
haystack = open("haystack.wav","rb").read()
for x in xrange(0, 10000):
 match = haystack.index(needle)` It took 15 seconds in Python and 3 seconds in PHP...

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent python code is this:

```
needle = open("needle.wav", "rb").read()[46:]

for x in range(0, 10000):
    haystack = open("haystack.wav", "rb").read()
    match = haystack.index(needle)
```

Comment: I would use `xrange`, since he is on 2.7.

Comment: php's range is not xrange.

Comment: @rubik: to be fair, the PHP code also inefficiently creates a giant array for no good reason. But OTOH optimizing by benchmarking which slow interpreted language to select by writing non-optimized code in both is... odd.

Comment: Ahh I missed that, I have fixed the code but Python performance is still the same. I also change to xrange..